# What is the difference between Scrollable and ScrolledComposite in swt?

Tags: java, swt, jface

What i could understand after seeing the seeing the internal implementation it seems that Scrollable class is used to draw scroll bars with the use of native os libraries. Now my question is why there is a need of ScrolledComposite which makes composite scrollable. means the scrolling functionality could have been achieved by Scrollable class only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scrollable` is a *abstract* class so it can't be used directly. It only provides very basic support for scroll bars and needs to be extended to make this useful.

Several different classes extend `Scrollable` to provide scrolling including `ScrolledComposite`, and `Text`. `ScrolledComposite` in particular provides all of what you need to scroll a child `Composite` without have to write any more code.